# Is there an equivalent of Pythons range(12) in C#?

Tags: c#, python, range, xrange

This crops up every now and then for me: I have some C# code badly wanting the `range()` function available in Python.

I am aware of using

```
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
   // add code here
}
```

But this brakes down in functional usages, as when I want to do a Linq `Sum()` instead of writing the above loop.

Is there any builtin? I guess I could always just roll my own with a `yield` or such, but this would be *so* handy to just *have*.

Comment: It's not Enumeration.Range, it's Enumerable.Range.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You're looking for the [`Enumerable.Range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range) method:

```
var mySequence = Enumerable.Range(0, 12);
```

Comment: Note: this requires System.Linq and C# 3.0.

Comment: crb: C#3 is not required. You can use this class from C# 2 but you need to reference the System.Core wich is in the .NET 3.5 framework.

Comment: This is confusing because I believe Python's version is `(start, end)` where .NET's version is `(start, count)` - don't make the mistake of mixing them up!

Answer (score 17):

Just to complement everyone's answers, I thought I should add that `Enumerable.Range(0, 12);` is closer to Python 2.x's `xrange(12)` because it's an enumerable.

If anyone requires specifically a list or an array:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 12).ToList();
```

or

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 12).ToArray();
```

are closer to Python's `range(12)`.

Answer (score 8):

```
Enumerable.Range(start, numElements);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
namespace CustomExtensions
{
    public static class Py
    {
        // make a range over [start..end) , where end is NOT included (exclusive)
        public static IEnumerable<int> RangeExcl(int start, int end)
        {
            if (end <= start) return Enumerable.Empty<int>();
            // else
            return Enumerable.Range(start, end - start);
        }

        // make a range over [start..end] , where end IS included (inclusive)
        public static IEnumerable<int> RangeIncl(int start, int end)
        {
            return RangeExcl(start, end + 1);
        }
    } // end class Py
}
```

Usage:

```
using CustomExtensions;

Py.RangeExcl(12, 18);    // [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]

Py.RangeIncl(12, 18);    // [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
```

Comment: When you provide a wrapper, why not also implementing the whole Python range function with one argument and three arguments?

Comment: @ChrisoLosoph Feel free to extend it.

Comment: Thanks. There is a better custom solution in this stack overflow answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67597048
You obviously didn't compile your code example, it does not compile from itself. I think, a good answer should provide compilable code examples, at least tested online. I will edit your answer to remedy it.

Comment: @ChrisoLosoph Given how much your proposed edit changed the original code, I rejected it and I suggest that you post it as an answer yourself.

Comment: @ChrisoLosoph I extracted this part from here: https://github.com/jabbalaci/JabbaCustomExtensions-for-C-Sharp . It has several unit tests.

Answer (score 3):

Enumerable.Range(0,12);

Comment: This lazy answer should be better explained.