# C# equivalent of Python's range with step?

Tags: c#, python, range, ienumerable

Is there a C# equivalent of Python's [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) with `step`?

---

**Documentation:**

> For a positive `step`, the contents of a range `r` are determined by the formula `r[i] = start + step*i` where `i >= 0` and `r[i] < stop`.
>
> For a negative `step`, the contents of the range are still determined by the formula `r[i] = start + step*i`, but the constraints are `i >= 0` and `r[i] > stop`.

---

**Example:**

```
>>> list(range(0, 10, 3))
[0, 3, 6, 9]
>>> list(range(0, -10, -1))
[0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9]
```

Comment: `Enumerable.Range(0, ((stop-start)/step) + ((stop-start)%step == 0 ? 0 : 1 )).Select(i => start + step * i)`

Comment: C# also has ranges now (with the syntax `start..end`), but afaik it doesn't support a step parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can implement a `static` utility class to handle this.

For completeness, this solution mimics Python's `range` behavior for one parameter (`stop`), two parameters (`start`, `stop`), and three parameters (`start`, `stop`, `step`):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class EnumerableUtilities
{
    public static IEnumerable<int> RangePython(int start, int stop, int step = 1)
    {
        if (step == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("Parameter step cannot equal zero.");

        if (start < stop && step > 0)
        {
            for (var i = start; i < stop; i += step)
            {
                yield return i;
            }
        }
        else if (start > stop && step < 0)
        {
            for (var i = start; i > stop; i += step)
            {
                yield return i;
            }
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<int> RangePython(int stop)
    {
        return RangePython(0, stop);
    }
}
```

---

**Example Usage with Step:**

```
foreach (var i in EnumerableUtilities.RangePython(0, 10, 3))
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

---

**Output:**

```
0
3
6
9
```

Answer (score 6):

I would go with two methods implementation. First one for parameters validation and providing defaults:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Range(int start, int stop, int step = 1)
{
    if (step == 0)
        throw new ArgumentException(nameof(step));

    return RangeIterator(start, stop, step);
}
```

That is required for iterators with deferred execution. Otherwise, you will not validate arguments until iterator will be executed. Which might happen a long time after you get an iterator reference. And iterator itself (actually with C# 7 you can use a [local function](http://thebillwagner.com/Blog/Item/2016-03-02-C7FeatureProposalLocalFunctions) instead of creating separate method):

```
private static IEnumerable<int> RangeIterator(int start, int stop, int step)
{
    int x = start;

    do
    {
        yield return x;
        x += step;
        if (step < 0 && x <= stop || 0 < step && stop <= x)
            break;
    }
    while (true);
}
```

To implement Python's range behavior we need one more method which accepts only *stop* parameter. We can simplify code with C# 6 expression-bodied member:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Range(int stop) => RangeIterator(0, stop, 1);
```

You also can make [static methods available in global scope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn879355.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) with C# 6. Assume class with Range method description is named PythonUtils:

```
using static YourNamespace.PythonUtils;
```

And usage in code will look like

```
foreach(var i in Range(0, 10, 3))
   Print(i);
```

You can also use default values

```
Range(0, 10, 3)     // [0,3,6,9]
Range(4, -3, -1)    // [4,3,2,1,0,-1,-2]
Range(5)            // [0,1,2,3,4]
Range(2, 5)         // [2,3,4]
```

Looks like Pascal-case Python :)

Comment: I like this solution better than my own, just a few things I'd like to point out: `range()` is not valid in Python, and `range(5)` should return `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`. I didn't specify these scenarios in my original question, I just included them in my answer just to make it feel as Python-like as possible.

Comment: @budi sorry, I have forgotten details of Python's range. Updated answer with additional Range method. And I have removed some defaults from  Range method with three parameters

Comment: Nitpicking here, but `list(range(1, -3, 2))` in python returns `[]`, however your solution `Range(1, -3, 2)` returns `[1]`. I've unaccepted for now, since my solution handled this case; I'll gladly re-accept if you want to update your solution!

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by Sergey's solution and mimics python's range.

```cs
static class Utils
{
    public static IEnumerable<int> Range(int start, int stop, int step = 1)
    {
        if (step == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(step));

        while (step > 0 && start < stop || step < 0 && start > stop)
        {
            yield return start;
            start += step;
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<int> Range(int stop) => Range(0, stop, 1);
}

void Main()
{
    var ranges = new IEnumerable<int>[] {
        Utils.Range(0, 10, 3),    // [0,3,6,9]
        Utils.Range(4, -3, -1),   // [4,3,2,1,0,-1,-2]
        Utils.Range(5),           // [0,1,2,3,4]
        Utils.Range(2, 5),        // [2,3,4]
        Utils.Range(1, -3, 2),    // []
    };
    
    Array.ForEach(ranges, Console.WriteLine);
}
```

A small optimization can be made to the while loop for better performance, which I like.

```cs
if (step > 0) while (start < stop)
{
    yield return start;
    start += step;
}
else while (start > stop)
{
    yield return start;
    start += step;
}
```

There might be a clever-er way to do this.